# "No Transport" error submitting html contact form to php script on same server

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm using a simple html contact form to submit contact details to a php file using Ajax / jQuery (v 1.10.2). The php sends an email and returns an error or "OK" on success. However I'm getting a "No Transport" error when I click the Submit button and the form isn't submitting.

I have a html form element with an id and I'm using "$('#contactForm').submit" in jQuery to submit the form. The strange thing is that it worked maybe 3 or 4 times in the past few days, so it works at random now and again. I tried not using jQuery and adding an action method directly to the form element (form action="inc/sendEmail.php" method="post") and this works, however the web page then redirects to the php file but I want to stay on the html page and not redirect.
- I searched for ajax and "no transport" error and most of the replies mention CORS, but my js is just calling a php script on the same server so it can't be anything to do with CORS (can it?)
- This was working a few months ago but I recently added SSL to the domain, but again I can't see how this can make a difference as the html, js, and php are all on the same server.

```
<form id="contactForm">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="InputName">Your Name</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="InputName" id="InputName" placeholder="Enter Name" required>
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="InputEmail">Your Email</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="InputEmail" name="InputEmail" placeholder="Enter Email" required  >
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="InputMessage">Message</label>
            <div class="input-group">
                <textarea name="InputMessage" id="InputMessage" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Email" rows="5" required></textarea>
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok form-control-feedback"></i></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn">
    </div>
</form>
```

---

```
$('#contactForm').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var contactName = $('#contactForm #InputName').val();
    var contactEmail = $('#contactForm #InputEmail').val();
    var contactSubject = '';
    var contactMessage = $('#contactForm #InputMessage').val();
    var data = 'contactName=' + contactName + '&contactEmail=' + contactEmail +
    '&contactSubject=' + contactSubject + '&contactMessage=' + contactMessage;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "inc/sendEmail.php",
        data: data,
        async: false,     
        success: function(msg) {
            // Message was sent
            if (msg == 'OK') {
                $('#message-warning').hide();
                $('#contactForm').fadeOut();
                $('#message-success').fadeIn();   
            }
            // There was an error
            else {
                $('#message-warning').html(msg);
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err)
        {
            // GETTING "No Transport" ERROR HERE
            $('#message-warning').html('Error message: ' + err);
            $('#message-warning').fadeIn();
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

---

```
<?php

$siteOwnersEmail = 'abc@xyz.com';

if($_POST) {

    $name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactName']));
    $email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactEmail']));
    $subject = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactSubject']));
    $contact_message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactMessage']));

    // Check Name
    if (strlen($name) < 2) {
        $error['name'] = "Please enter your name.";
    }
    // Check Email
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {
        $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
    }
    // Check Message
    if (strlen($contact_message) < 15) {
        $error['message'] = "Please enter your message. It should have at least 15 characters.";
    }
    // Subject
    if ($subject == '') { $subject = "Contact form submission"; }

    // Set Message
    $message .= "Email from: " . $name . "<br />";
    $message .= "Email address: " . $email . "<br />";
    $message .= "Message: <br />";
    $message .= $contact_message;
    $message .= "<br /> ----- <br /> This email was sent from your site's contact form. <br />";

    // Set From: header
    $from =  $name . " <" . $email . ">";

    // Email Headers
    $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

    if (!$error) {

        ini_set("sendmail_from", $siteOwnersEmail); // for windows server
        $mail = mail($siteOwnersEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);

        if ($mail) { echo "OK"; }
        else { echo "Something went wrong. Please try again."; }

    } # end if - no validation error
    else {

        $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? $error['name'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? $error['email'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['message'])) ? $error['message'] . "<br />" : null;

        echo $response;
    } # end if - there was a validation error
}   
?>
```

I expect the form to be submitted to the php script when the input fields are valid, then the contact form should be hidden if an OK message comes back from the php. However I'm getting a "No Transport" error when I click submit and the form isn't being submitted at all (there's no entry in the "Network" panel in browser dev tools).

Comment: `async: false` is deprecated, you should stop using it as it produces a bad user experience (locks the browser UI while the AJAX runs) - and since it's deprecated you can expect it to stop working at some point when browsers remove it. Anyway, you don't need it because you're using your callbacks properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I figured it out. It looks like there was an issue with ajax submitting to the php file over SSL - even though the path to the php file is relative and the site is already on https. I read that an older version of the jquery library may have this issue so I upgraded to a higher version (1.10.2 to 1.11.3) which seems to have fixed the issue. More testing required but it looks good so far.